# angularjs, coding style, use of global variable

Tags: angularjs

I see a lot of Angular codes more like this. 
The following one is from their tutorial.

```
angular.module('phonecat', ['phonecatFilters', 'phonecatServices']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',   controller: PhoneListCtrl}).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html', controller: PhoneDetailCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/phones'});
}]);
```

However, I am more familiar with like this;

```
var app = angular.module('phonecat', ['phonecatFilters', 'phonecatServices']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',   controller: PhoneListCtrl}).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html', controller: PhoneDetailCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/phones'});
}]);
```

I even want to define that `function($routeProvider) { ...}` as a variable, but I am not confident about that will work.

Is there a reason behind this to avoid global variable, in this case `app`.

Or it's just one of best practices in AngularJs community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular.module(..) returns a module, and you can;

1. assign to a variable app(which is a global variable).
2. or continue chaining it

You saw a lot of chained examples because it is in a single file.

You will also see a lot of examples using global variable 'app' or whatever, because codes needs to be organized to many files.

I recommend the first one if you make an single file example.
I recommend the second one if you make an actual app, which requires name spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Namespacing is good. Best practive is using `angular.value` instead of global variables

```
app.value('myVariable', 'myValue')
   .controller('myController', function($scope, myVariable) {
       ...
    });
```

Comment: Maybe that helps you: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/

Comment: y i like namespacing, but it seems AngularJS does not do that way, such as app.router, app.controller, app.filter, etc. Want to know reason behind it. There must be.

Comment: app.router or app.controller is a namespacing too. You have only one global variable(app) and every part of module belongs to `app` variable. Nothing new here, it's not Angular's finding.